# Demo app on heroku gives Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorials screen cast series and having trouble in deploying demo `Rails` application in `Heroku`. The deploy is successful but when I try to open the URl, it gives an Application Error

The link for the app is http://evening-lake-3818.herokuapp.com/ . Please Help !!

Comment: Use your heroku console to get logs.

Comment: Please mention the error also..

Comment: run `heroku log -t` in a console and then re hit the home page and watch the output. You can post it back here, but it should give you the next step to do. You can also add the "Papertrail" heroku add on, which gives you web access to this same log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've not used **`rake db:migrate`**

---

**Heroku**

This error is a `heroku` error (not a `rails` problem) - the typical Rails errors are the `red` error page, which says something like "Something went wrong" or "Page Cannot Be Found":

[image]

The error **you** are seeing is a Heroku problem, and is typically because you've either not set up your production database, or you have not got the required migrations to make it work.

The way to fix this is to run:

```
# heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Other than that, you'll also need to ensure you have the `config/database.yml` set up correctly for your production environment (which I can help you with if you need it)